# Symfony2: twig filters inside transchoice

Tags: symfony, internationalization, translation

I am using Symfony2, Twig and xliff based translations.

Now, I want to show text based on a numerical value which is between `[-Inf,Inf]`. To do that, I use [`transchoice`](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/translation.html#pluralization).

**My problem**: I want to display `7 days ago` if `count=-7`. However, I get `-7 days ago`. I can't use twig filters like `abs` inside transchoice fields, right? How do I remove the leading minus sign.

Here is my `message.en.xliff`...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
               <source>todo.days-difference</source>
                   <target>{0} today|{1} tommorow|]1,14] %count% days before|]14,Inf] far away|{-1} yesterday|[-14,-1[{{ count }}%count% days after|[-Inf,-14[ long after</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

passing the absolute value of the count variable as argument solves the problem:

```
    {{ "todo.days-differences"|transchoice(task.getDueDateDifference(), {'%count_abs%': task.getDueDateDifference()|abs}) }}

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
        <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
            <body>
                <trans-unit id="1">
                   <source>todo.days-difference</source>
                       <target>{0} today|{1} tommorow|]1,14] %count_abs% days before|]14,Inf] far away|{-1} yesterday|[-14,-1[ %count_abs% days after|[-Inf,-14[ long after</target>
                </trans-unit>
            </body>
        </file>
    </xliff>
```